# xCode - UIDatePicker AM and PM rollers not reacting correctly to setDate

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to set a UIDatePicker to today's date, but the picker isn't behaving.

The code I'm using is pretty simple:

.h

```
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)setForCurrent:(id)sender
{

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

[datePicker setDate:today animated:YES];

}
```

When I hit the button that is linked to the setForCurrent action, the picker does shift the Day, Month, Hours, and Minutes to the current time.

The issue is that the AM/PM roller always shifts to PM if the current time is in the AM. What is odd is that I've used NSLog to see what date the picker is seeing (`datePicker.date`) , and it is the correct date.

When the button is hit a second time, the AM/PM roller shifts to be correct again.

Is there some way to work around this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it helps but I had similar problem. In my case when I set

> datePicker.date = [NSDate date]

it showed date behind some hours and it depended on time zone I chose on iPhone. May be it is sdk bug but I fixed it by setting

> datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone
>   localTimeZone]